# How to have first level as column chart and second level as Fixed placement columns in drill down highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am stuck in highcharts to create drilldown charts having column chart in first level and **[Fixed placement columns](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-placement)** in the second level.  I googled and got a sample which is reverse of my requirement. 
[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/34g8qxkb/1/)

So sample code follows

```
$(function () {
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            },
            grouping: false            
        }
    },        

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',            
        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33,
            drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 24.03,
            drilldown: 'Chrome'
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.38,
            drilldown: 'Firefox'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Brands2',
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 24.77,
            drilldown: 'Safari'
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 20.91,
            drilldown: 'Opera'
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 7.2,
            drilldown: null
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            data: [
                [
                    'v11.0',
                    24.13
                ],
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    17.2
                ],
                [
                    'v9.0',
                    8.11
                ],
                [
                    'v10.0',
                    5.33
                ],
                [
                    'v6.0',
                    1.06
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    0.5
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            id: 'Chrome',
            data: [
                [
                    'v40.0',
                    5
                ],
                [
                    'v41.0',
                    4.32
                ],
                [
                    'v42.0',
                    3.68
                ],
                [
                    'v39.0',
                    2.96
                ],
                [
                    'v36.0',
                    2.53
                ],
                [
                    'v43.0',
                    1.45
                ],
                [
                    'v31.0',
                    1.24
                ],
                [
                    'v35.0',
                    0.85
                ],
                [
                    'v38.0',
                    0.6
                ],
                [
                    'v32.0',
                    0.55
                ],
                [
                    'v37.0',
                    0.38
                ],
                [
                    'v33.0',
                    0.19
                ],
                [
                    'v34.0',
                    0.14
                ],
                [
                    'v30.0',
                    0.14
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            id: 'Firefox',
            data: [
                [
                    'v35',
                    2.76
                ],
                [
                    'v36',
                    2.32
                ],
                [
                    'v37',
                    2.31
                ],
                [
                    'v34',
                    1.27
                ],
                [
                    'v38',
                    1.02
                ],
                [
                    'v31',
                    0.33
                ],
                [
                    'v33',
                    0.22
                ],
                [
                    'v32',
                    0.15
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            id: 'Safari',
            data: [
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    2.56
                ],
                [
                    'v7.1',
                    0.77
                ],
                [
                    'v5.1',
                    0.42
                ],
                [
                    'v5.0',
                    0.3
                ],
                [
                    'v6.1',
                    0.29
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    0.26
                ],
                [
                    'v6.2',
                    0.17
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            id: 'Opera',
            data: [
                [
                    'v12.x',
                    0.34
                ],
                [
                    'v28',
                    0.24
                ],
                [
                    'v27',
                    0.17
                ],
                [
                    'v29',
                    0.16
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
});
```

How to have reverse drilldown of the above existing code

Comment: I am not understanding what you want. Explain what you mean by "reverse drill down". When you click "____", you want "____" to happen?

Comment: @jlbriggs how to create  drilldown charts having column chart in first level and Fixed placement columns in the second level

Comment: drill down charts have series id linked to drilldown series . but my problem is how to populate Fixed placement columns in second level

Comment: OK. So, for starters, the "fixed placement" columns are still just columns, which need a second series. Take a look at this answer, which addresses how to drill down to multiple series using a callback on the drilldown event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313600/highchart-drilldown-to-simultaneous-multiple-series-and-y-axis

Comment: @jlbriggs many many thanks. this solved my problem. And my answer is below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of inputs from jlbriggs, I am able to solve my problem

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/34g8qxkb/2/)

So Code below. Hope it helps community

```
$(function() {
  // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      events: {
        drilldown: function(e) {
          var chart = this,
            drilldowns = chart.userOptions.drilldown.series,
            series = [];
          e.preventDefault();
          Highcharts.each(drilldowns, function(p, i) {
            if (p.id.includes(e.point.name)) {
              chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, p);
            }
          });
          chart.applyDrilldown();
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: [{
      title: {
        text: 'Total percent market share'
      }

    }, {
      title: {
        text: 'cost'
      },
      opposite: true
    }],
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
        }
      }
        ,column: {
                grouping: false,
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
    },

    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
      pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Brands',
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [{
        name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
        y: 56.33,
        drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
      }, {
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 24.03,
        drilldown: 'Chrome'
      }, {
        name: 'Firefox',
        y: 10.38,
        drilldown: 'Firefox'
      }, {
        name: 'Safari',
        y: 4.77,
        drilldown: 'Safari'
      }, {
        name: 'Opera',
        y: 0.91,
        drilldown: 'Opera'
      }, {
        name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
        y: 0.2,
        drilldown: null
      }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
      series: [{
        name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
        id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
        type: 'column',
        color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
        pointPadding: 0.3,
        pointPlacement: -0.2,
        data: [
          ['v11', 25],
          ['v8', 17],
          ['v9', 8],
          ['v10', 5],
          ['v7', 3]
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer Cost',
        id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
        type: 'column',
        color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        pointPlacement: -0.2,
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [
          ['v11', 50],
          ['v8', 40],
          ['v9', 60],
          ['v10', 65],
          ['v7', 73]
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'Chrome',
        id: 'Chrome',
        data: [
          ['v40.0', 5],
          ['v41.0', 4.32],
          ['v42.0', 3.68]
        ]
      }]
    }
  });
});
```